# Is it OK to do an https redirect from http?

Tags: html, node.js, http, https, socket.io

I have a web application that uses node.js and the socket.io library, in addition to a postgresql database. It is hosted on heroku. For the socket.io library I get an error message if I run my code with the site address typed in as "http://X" but not when I try "https://X"
To fix this error I forcibly redirect the user to the https site if they visit the http version. Here is my code for doing this.

```
<script>
  if (document.URL.indexOf("https") == -1 && document.URL.indexOf("localhost") == -1)
  {
    window.location.href = document.URL.replace("http", "https");
  }
</script>
```

Is there any reason why this is a bad idea? Is there a better solution? Any comments on the distinction between http and https would be appreciated. Here is the error I get when running the site on http:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://theland.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=<not sure if I should share this part of the url...>' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake`: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing
```

To clarify, the site works fine with my solution now, but I am worried about whether or not my solution is "good practice".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wrote an answer, is it helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On client side, it's enough to include Socket.IO without the URL:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script> const socket = io(); </script>
```

Another option is to use the URL with:

```
wss://yourURL
```

If that doesn't work, a better approach is to redirect from the server side, like:

```
app.get('/anyURL', (req, res) => {

    if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) !== null || !req.secure) {
        return res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host.replace(/^www\./, '') + req.url);
    };
});
```